# Moving GUI Builder components between spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I think I may have just painted myself into a corner...

Is there any way to move a UI component built in Google's GUI Builder for a Google Spreadsheet script into another spreadsheet?

I've developed a GUI using the GUI Builder in a test sheet, but now I want to use it in a different, already existing working spreadsheet. I can't find any way to move it. If it can't be moved, is there some way to serialize and store the elements of the UI so that I can read those in from a new script in another spreadsheet. I'd even be happy with copy and paste as part of the solution (this is how I move scripts around, after all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the feature you are asking for is still in development.
You can track it here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=999

One work around you can employ is convert your test project into a library. For more information please read this user guide:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries#writingLibrary

Comment: Brilliant! The libraries feature does the trick and is a much cleaner way to share code than my old copy/paste method. And, yes, it shares the GUI Builder components as well. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to copy the Ui components its to make a copy of the spreadsheet. Then copy the data you want to use.  This is why I don't use the Ui builder!